# VBA - Looping through filtered table in access

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

Access 2013 32 Bit / Windows 7 64 Bit

I have a table of keys and based on the key value my vba will run some queries and populate other fields in the table - I call this "Checking" I have a "Checked" Column in the table and have to break the processing of this list into several batches (and more records are constantly added) so I'd like to filter out the "Checked" ones. I'd like to do this **WITHOUT** using a separate query

I'm using the traditional loop w/ a condition:
(My code works this is just a mock up ignore syntax here please)

```
Move First
Do Until EOF
if Table("Checked") = "True" Then goto NextRow
    <Code>
NextRow:
    Move Next
Loop
```

I'd like to continue with this method, but filter out all of the `"Checked" = True` on the onset

Comment: Have you tried creating a query with `Checked = "True"` criteria?

Comment: I've thought about it - It's what I'm going to do if there isn't a filter option, but ideally I'd just filter out the data

Comment: `RecordSet` does have a `Filter` property but I'm pretty sure it is more efficient to use a sql statement with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why are you opposed to using a query as the data source for the recordset?

Comment: I didn't want to have to run an update query on the main table from the query that showed the unchecked items to mark them as checked. It was just easier to filter the table and iterate through to create the queries and mark them as checked if I stayed in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sorting the field then exiting the sub when I reached a row marked as checked.

Answer (score 1):

Simply open your recordset with a query that has a WHERE clause.

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim S As String

S = "SELECT foo, morefoo FROM bar WHERE [Checked] = 0"
' Or if Checked is a Text column:
S = "SELECT foo, morefoo FROM bar WHERE [Checked] <> 'True'"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(S)
Do While Not rs.EOF
    ' code

    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

(BTW, your `Move First` inside the loop would create an endless loop...)

Comment: Yeah my mistake with the move first inside - I was throwing out a concept.

I ideally don't want to run off of a query -- this post is asking for an alternative to that - I'll clean up the question to reflect and clarify that goal. Thank you

Comment: @Schalton: Sorry, but this doesn't make much sense. You must filter the records either with the recordset (by using a WHERE clause, see my answer) or in the loop (see your question). There is no other way.

Comment: He could open an ADO Recordset, and then set its `Filter` property.  That works as I think he intends.  But I don't understand why it makes sense to do it that way.  It should be more efficient to load only the target rows in the first place --- as you suggested.